# Echoing using PHP to an existing div

Tags: php, echo

I have a PHP function which returns this :

`echo '<li>Welcome back.</li>'` I would like that `echo` to be appended to an existing div on the html called `<div id="messages"></div>`

Is there any way of doing this with just simple `echo` or I should use Jquery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using php all you can do is to run your function inside the div

```
<div id="messages">
    <?php run_function_here();?>
</div>
```